# MySQL data insertion error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Please find the error in this code , I am trying to save the data but it's not storing 
using Eclipse , MySQL , 64 bit

**Error** :

> java.sql.SQLException: [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.28]You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database
>   ('did','dname','dadress','salary','sex','specialist','cell#')VALUES
>   (?,' at line 1

```
package pk.pucit;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class DoctorsRecord {

public JFrame frm=new JFrame("Doctor's Record Information");
public  JButton btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4;
public  JLabel lbl1,lbl2,lbl3,lbl4,lbl5,lbl6,lblr;
public JTextField txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4,txt5,txt6,txt7;
public  JRadioButton rbtn1,rbtn2;
//frm.setBackground(Color.green);

public DoctorsRecord(){
    lbl1=new JLabel("Doctor ID");
    lbl2=new JLabel("Doctor's Name");
    lbl3=new JLabel("Address");
    lblr=new JLabel("Gender");
    lbl4=new JLabel("Salary");
    lbl5=new JLabel("Rank");
    lbl6=new JLabel("Ph #");


    txt1=new JTextField(7);
    txt2=new JTextField(7);
    txt3=new JTextField(7);
    txt4=new JTextField(7);
    txt5=new JTextField(7);
    txt6=new JTextField(7);
    txt7=new JTextField(7);

    /*rbtn1=new JRadioButton("Male");
    rbtn2=new JRadioButton("Female");*/

    btn1=new JButton("Save");
    btn2=new JButton("Search ");
    btn3=new JButton("Reset");
    btn4=new JButton("Cancel");

    JPanel pnl1=new JPanel();

    pnl1.add(lbl1);
    pnl1.add(txt1);
    pnl1.add(lbl2);
    pnl1.add(txt2);
    pnl1.add(lbl3);
    pnl1.add(txt3);
    pnl1.add(lblr);
    pnl1.add(txt7);
    pnl1.add(lbl4);
    pnl1.add(txt4);
    pnl1.add(lbl5);
    pnl1.add(txt5);
    pnl1.add(lbl6);
    pnl1.add(txt6);
    pnl1.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,1));

    JPanel pnl=new JPanel();

    pnl.add(btn1);
    pnl.add(btn2);
    pnl.add(btn3);
    pnl.add(btn4);
    pnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    frm.add(pnl1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frm.add(pnl,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //frm.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,1));
    frm.setBounds(400,100,400,500);
    frm.setVisible(true);
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            try{
                String id=txt1.getText();
                String name=txt2.getText();
                String add=txt3.getText();
                String sal=txt4.getText();
                String sex=txt5.getText();
                String sep=txt6.getText();
                String cell=txt7.getText();
                dataHandler(id,name,add,sal,sex,sep,cell);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception occur");
            }
        } 

    }
            );
}
    public void dataHandler(String id,String dn,String add,String sal,String   sex,String sep,String cell)throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Dbms", "root", "root");
    String query = "insert into database    ('did','dname','dadress','salary','sex','specialist','cell#')" +"VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
       PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, dn);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, add);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, sal);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, sex);
        preparedStatement.setString(6, sep);
        preparedStatement.setString(7, cell);
        preparedStatement.execute();
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception oc){
        System.out.println(oc.toString());
    }
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        new DoctorsRecord();

    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not do code debugging. You need to do your own debugging and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what is is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: do you have a table called "database" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with you query.

**First**, `DataBase` is a Reserved Keyword, you must escape it with backtick.

```
String query = "insert into `database` (did,dname,dadress,salary,sex,specialist,`cell#`) 
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

**Second**, the column names must not be wrap with single quotes. because if you do that, it will also generate an error telling you that the column was not found. Only `columnNames` and `tableNames` can be enclosed with backtick.

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Thanx Bro , but still not saving the data :-(

Answer (score 0):

Database is a reserved keyword. You have to escape it properly in order to use it as a table name.

```
INSERT INTO `database` ...
```

Comment: is it correct to enclose field names with single quotes like you did? And is it allowed to use the # sign in code? I think the fields must be enclosed like the way you did for database but not the fields.

Comment: thanx ,i got your point but still not working ,

Comment: Thanx to all of you , it's working now ,